# Laravel Jetstream profile-photos not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-jetstream

Why laravel jetstream profile photos not showing?

i used This command and he didn't work

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I deleted the storage folder inside the public folder

And I executed the following command to delete temporary files

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

nothing happened same problem

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: is the public folder your _document root_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.